# Query fields using elastic search to get only field value and not whole dictionary

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a dictionary as below

```
dict1=
{"name":"Max", "age":"10"}

dict2=
{"name":"Max", "age":"10"}

dict3=
{"name":"Well", "age":"10"}
```

Now what is the query to get only the "name" field for specific string using elastic search?

For example. Search for name fields which has "Max" as the name.
Output should be:

```
name:Max

name:Max
```

OR

```
Max
Max
```

The below queries returned the whole dictionary for me.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/cs/event/_search -d '{"query": {"query_string": {"name": "Max"}}}'| python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `?fields=something` to the `_search` request URL:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/cs/event/_search?fields=name -d '{"query": {"query_string": {"name": "Max"}}}'| python -m json.tool
```